# Update MongoDB document based on total amount of elements in two arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection named `groups` that among other things contain two arrays: `members` and `invited`. Each element in the arrays are user objects, e.g. `{ _id: '...', name: '...', ...}`

The document also contains a field called `maxMembers` which is an integer indicating how many members the group can have in total. I'd like to enforce a rule when updating the document that ensures that the number of element in the `members` array + the number of elements in the `invited` array never exceeds the `maxMembers` count.

The `maxMembers` will never change, so I am allowed to read this before hand if necessary (though reading it atomically would be awesome).

If this was just a single `members` array I would do it like so:

```
var id = ... // the id of the document
var users = {...} // a user's object
var max = ... // the max amount of users read from `maxMembers` previously

var query = { _id: id, 'members._id': { $ne: user._id } }
query['members.' + max] = { $exists: false }

db.groups.update(query, { $push: { members: user } })
```

But this will of cause not work if I have to take into account the number of elements in the `invited` array as well.

Is there a way to do this atomically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there is not any "great" way to handle this atomically since update operators cannot actually "read" the values of document properties in their current state. The exception being things like [**`$inc`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) that will just modify the current value atomically with an "increment/decrement" depending on whether that is a positive or negative value in the assignment.

You "could" combine your query condition in the update with [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) logic, but that does in itself have some limitations.

As an example:

```js
db.things.insert({ "a": [1,2,3], "maxA": 4 })
```

Defines a document with an array containing three members, and another field "maxA" which is our intended "governer" for the maximum length of the array.

```js
db.things.update(
    { "$where": "return this.a.length+1 <= this.maxA"},
    { "$push": { "a": 4 } }
)
```

And that of course allows the new additional element addition would still be less than or equal to the maximum governed length, so the document is a match and the update is made.

Hoever if your then tried after that update:

```js
db.things.update(
    { "$where": "return this.a.length+1 <= this.maxA"},
    { "$push": { "a": 5 } }
)
```

Then since that exceeds the governed total length then the document does not update since there is no match.

Of course you could extend upon that with [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/slice/) to allow new items at the end for maximum length:

```js
db.things.update(
    { "$where": "return this.a.length == this.maxA"},
    { "$push": { "a": { "$each": [5], "$slice": -4 } } }
)
```

But the operation cannot be "truly" self contained, considering that you would need to read the document first in order to get the "maxA" value for use with `$slice`. However, as long as that value did not change after being read then that operation is "still" an "atomic" one, albeit that you did need to read something first.

But it is possible this way since the JavaScript evaluation will govern the match, even if the values cannot be used in the update itself.

But if you do want to go down this path, then please try to use `$where` only alongside other query conditions to match the expected document. In that way the native query operators can use an "index" to select, which `$where` alone cannot. So it really only should be used as a "final filter" to the other conditions present in the query condition.

Comment: Works like charm - thanks :) Just to make sure there is no misunderstandings: I didn't want the array to be a kind of sliding window keeping only the last `maxA` elements. I just wanted the update statement to not do anything in case the max was reached, so your initial idea using `$where` works fine. This is now my implementation: `$where: 'return (this.members || []).length + (this.invited || []).length < this.maxMembers'`

Comment: Oh and yeah, you are absolutely correct in that I should not depend on the `$where` clause being the only query element. In my case I know the ID of the document I want to update, to I'll use that as my primary lookup key, and the just add the `$where` part as a kind of guard if you will to ensure that the max is kept

Comment: @ThomasWatson That is kind of it. And funny enough, just answered another question asking about `$where` in conjuction with the "exact match" on an `_id` field. So it sounds like you have the right things in mind. Have you actually considered "one" array and just putting a "type" on the subdocument information? Or do you need to move "members" in between the lists? In which case the two array form makes sense. The response here was really just a "guide" since your actual ( length of two arrays ) seemed open to interpretation as to what you needed to do. So general to be useful.

Comment: @BlakeStevens Yeah, I've considered a single array, but it's just so nice that I don't have to worry about confising actual members with invited users in other parts of my code - so I would like to see if there was a way to keep them separate - and it seems like this is actually a great way. Yes, I move members between the lists :)

Comment: @ThomasWatson Just for others reference, it is the "moving between lists" that makes this absolutely the correct thing to do. The general case there being `$push/$pull` operations, where you cannot do "both" within the same update operation on the same path. That is why separate lists are a design requirement for such handling.